# Convert the date & time to GMT+10 date & time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I want to convert my local time to GMT+10 time. I am using asp.net and my website is hosted in azure. And in after get that date & time it should be set to ActivityDate in below code.

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo;
DateTime dateTime;
timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Australia Standard Time");
dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, timeZoneInfo);
DateTime AusDateTime= dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");


_activityService.InsertActivity(new ActivityDto { UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, ActivityType = ActivityConstants.ACT_TYPE_USR_MGT, ActivityDescription = ActivityConstants.USR_MGT_DESCR_FORGOT_PW, ActivityDate = DateTime.Now });
```

Comment: Well you're not *using* AusDateTime... you're still using `ActivityDate = DateTime.Now`. (I'd urge you to take your local time zone out of the picture though, using `DateTime.UtcNow`.)

Comment: As Jon said, you should always deal with UTC time and convert from UTC to local time when you need to display

Comment: Does DateTime.UtcNow work for my task?

Comment: Isn't there any method to pass the GMT+10 and DateTime.Now to get the Australian DateTime? I am just asking?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer for my question.

```
 var ActivityDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Australia Standard Time")) });
```